# java JNI error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java-native-interface

```
java -Djava.library.path=. TestJNI
>>>>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: TestJNI.calibrate([D[DII)[D
 at TestJNI.calibrate(Native Method)
 at TestJNI.main(TestJNI.java:61)
```

I know the library is getting loaded otherwise the error says cant find calibrate library.
what does the above error mean?

**EDIT**

this is my implementation-

```
JNIEXPORT jdoubleArray JNICALL Java_TestJNI_cailbrate (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj, jdoubleArray rtt, jdoubleArray distance ,jint activecount,jint passivecount) {
jdoubleArray jresult = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env,3);
 .......
return jresult;
}
```

are the parameters declared correctly?

Comment: You have a simple typing error: `Java_TestJNI_cailbrate` instead of `Java_TestJNI_calibrate`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This message means that Java is looking for a native method that looks like the Java method

```
double[] calibrate(double[], double[], int, int)
```

If you have generated your header files correctly, and built the library, this most likely means you are missing the implementation of that method.

Some things that come to mind:

- Did you rebuild the library after you implemented the method?
- Did you happen to change the interface of the Java method after you built the library?

Comment: There seems to be a typo: is that only in the question, or also in the code? `Java_TestJNI_cailbrate` vs. `calibrate`

Answer (score 2):

Another cause of this cryptic error is when you import the incorrect `<jni.h>` file. For instance, if you are compiling against x86 but point your `includes` path to the x64 flavor of the header.

Comment: Indeed, in my case I was stuck because of the exact same error, with the correct libraries as dependencies, however I forgot  `InitLocal.start()` which has resolved my problem, allowing me to continue. Thanks!