# Link Error in Java

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: model.JNIResultSet.getSpieler()[Lmodel/Spieler;
    at model.JNIResultSet.getSpieler(Native Method)
    at model.JNIResultSet.main(JNIResultSet.java:18)
```

My java classes look like this:

```
package model;

public class Spieler {
private String vorname;
private String nachname;
private int trikotnummer;


public Spieler(String vorname, String nachname, int trikotnummer) {
    this.vorname = vorname;
    this.nachname = nachname;
    this.trikotnummer = trikotnummer;
}
}
```

and

```
package model;

public class JNIResultSet {

public JNIResultSet() { }

public native Spieler[] getSpieler();

static {
    System.loadLibrary("spieler");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JNIResultSet jni = new JNIResultSet();
    Spieler s[] = jni.getSpieler();
    System.out.println("Laenge: " + s.length);
}


}
```

My header file looks like that:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class model_JNIResultSet */

#ifndef _Included_model_JNIResultSet
#define _Included_model_JNIResultSet
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
* Class:     model_JNIResultSet
* Method:    getSpieler
* Signature: ()[Lmodel/Spieler;
*/
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler
(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

And finally my C code looks like that:

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
JAVA_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

Spieler *ptr = head;
jobjectArray ret;
int i;
jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "model/Spieler");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "<init>", "(III)V");
jobject object; 

ret= (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count,
        clazz,
        NULL);

for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    object = (*env)->NewObject(env, clazz, mid, ptr);
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,
            ret, i, object);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}

return ret;
}
```

Do you have any suggestions how to fix that problem?
I also don't know if the C code is right, maybe that's the problem?

I execute it this way:

```
cd src
javac model/JNIResultSet.java
cd ..

cd bin
javah -jni model.JNIResultSet

gcc -fPIC -o libspieler.so -shared -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/include/ SharedTable.c -lc

java -Djava.library.path=/home/pupil/workspace/JNITableV2/bin/ model.JNIResultSet
```

Probably this is the error I've updated the C code but I think it's wrong:

```
jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "model/JNIResultSet");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "getSpieler", "()Lmodel/Spieler;");
```

`nm -D` reports:

U atoi
0000000000202088 B **bss_start

00000000002020b0 B current

w __cxa_finalize

0000000000202088 D _edata

00000000002022b8 B _end

U fclose

0000000000000ef0 T _fini

 U fopen

w __gmon_start**
00000000002020a8 B head
0000000000000948 T _init
0000000000000b35 T insertFirst
 U _IO_getc
 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000000ca2 T JAVA_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler
 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
 U malloc
 U memcpy
 U memset
0000000000000c49 T reverse
 U strcpy
00000000002020c0 B string
 U strlen

Comment: Does your .c file include the .h file? and does `javap -s` agree with the method signature you're using? and does `javah` agree with the current .h and .c files?

Comment: Yeah I included the .h file. And as you see the method in the .h file is the same as in the .c file.. Probably `findClass` or something else in the C code is the problem?

Comment: No, the linkage between the native Java method and the .c method is the problem. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: How can I include the `Spieler` class maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Include it in what? It's pure Java. As long as it's on the CLASSPATH it is available to JNI.

Comment: Oh please. You can see for yourself that that is totally illegible. Edit it into your question, and format it as code.

Comment: I've edited it now

Comment: There's nothing in the commands you've posted that shows how a Java compilation of `src/model/JNIResultSet.java` results in a file `bin/model/ResulSet.class`.

Comment: javac is the command I thought?

Comment: Certainly. So? Unless you've specified the `-d` option to `javac`, or you have a CLASSPATH environment variable that includes the `bin` directory, neither of which are shown, my comment stands.

Comment: I compiled `javac model/JNIResultSet.java` and both classes are in the model pkg

Comment: None of that addresses the issue. How did the .class file get from `src/model/JNIResultSet.class`, where the `javac` command put it, to `bin/model/JNIResultSet.class`? *Did* it get there? or are you still looking at an old one?

Comment: I copied the new one to the bin folder but it's still the same error

Comment: I've edited my post again.. Take a look at the last 2 lines if they're correct please

Comment: `jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "getSpieler", "()Lmodel/Spieler;");` doesn't make sense. That's trying get the native method that you're already executing. Pointless. I can't see any reason for using JNI here at all. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I read words from a file and create objects afterwards. Now they looks like that {"A", "B", 1}, {"C", "D", 2} etc. now I want to transfer them to java and insert them into a JTable. But I still get a linking error. This guy has the same problem, do you know how to solve it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526198/java-jni-error-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: He has a typo. Maybe you do too. You haven't addressed the question of why you would attempt to get the JNI jmethodID of a native method you're already executing. You don't need it.

Comment: And do you have a clue how to solve that?

Comment: I have a clue how to solve typing errors: don't make them; and I have a clue how to do unnecessary things: don't do them. Your point?

Comment: Thanks for you unuseful help @EJP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSpieler()` method could be declared static; you can use it without instantiating **JNIResultSet** class.

**mid** should point to the constructor, not `getSpieler()`, but the `<init>` signature is wrong: it should take `Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I` and not three `int`s:

```
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V");
…
jobject strVorname = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, ptr->vorname);
jobject strNachname = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, ptr->nachname);
object = (*env)->NewObject(env, clazz, mid, strVorname, strNachname, ptr->trikotnummer);
```

Always check the method IDs and objects for NULL before proceeding to the next step.

Regarding the unsatisfied link, <s>check that the **libspieler.so** file is good: run `nm -D` to see if `JAVA_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler` is actually exported.</s> rename `JAVA_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler` to `Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler`, exactly as indicated in the generated `.h` file.

Comment: And what could I write for the constructor instead of <init> ?

Comment: Where and how should I run nm -D? `nm -D libspieler.so`?

Comment: This guy has the same problem as me. How can I fix that in my example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526198/java-jni-error-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: Your C code uses the constructor of Java class, not the native method that it implements. Please see the edit - you also must give the parameters to the constructor!

Comment: What does your `nm -D` report?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125333/discussion-between-mafioso-and-alex-cohn).

Comment: Just one last question: How can I set the relative `java -Djava.library.path`? Currently the absolute looks like that: /home/....

Comment: probably you know the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005820/how-to-call-java-method-which-returns-string-from-c-using-jni

Answer (score -2):

It's probably a issue of `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable (on linux, not sure whats the environment key on windows). Trying add the directories to these variable, export them and run the application.

Try it in new session.

Comment: No. If that was the problem the exception would have been thrown by `loadLibrary()`. The library has been loaded successfully, so the problem is clearly what is *in* the library: almost certainly a disagreement between the Java method signature and what is in the C code.

Comment: @mafioso *Of course* it's the C code. It isn't satisfying the JNI linkage required.