# How to call Java method which returns String from C using JNI?

Tags: c, string, java-native-interface

Is there a way to call a java method, which returns a `String` in C?
For `Integer` it works like that:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Client_getAgeC(JNIEnv *env, jobject callingObject, jobject employeeObject) {
jclass employeeClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, employeeObject);
jmethodID midGetAge = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, employeeClass, "getAge", "()I");
int age =  (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, employeeObject, midGetAge);
return age;
}
```

I've searched for a long time but nothing works for `String`.
Finally, I want to get a `char*`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of JNI code calling a method returning a string. Hope this helps.

```
int EXT_REF Java_JNITest_CallJava(
    JNIEnv* i_pjenv, 
    jobject i_jobject
)
{
    jclass      jcSystem;
    jmethodID   jmidGetProperty;
    LPWSTR      wszPropName = L"java.version";

    jcSystem = i_pjenv->FindClass("java/lang/System");
    if(NULL == jcSystem)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    jmidGetProperty = i_pjenv->GetStaticMethodID(jcSystem,
                      "getProperty", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    if(NULL == jmidGetProperty)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    jstring joStringPropName = i_pjenv->NewString((const jchar*)wszPropName, wcslen(wszPropName));
    jstring joStringPropVal  = (jstring)i_pjenv->CallStaticObjectMethod(jcSystem, 
                               jmidGetProperty, (jstring)joStringPropName);
    const jchar* jcVal = i_pjenv->GetStringChars(joStringPropVal, JNI_FALSE);
    printf("%ws = %ws\n", wszPropName, jcVal);
    i_pjenv->ReleaseStringChars(joStringPropVal, jcVal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just have a jobject as a parameter and want to get a string of it. That can't be so difficult for `String` if it's so easy for `int`

Comment: You see, int is a primitive type returned by value - so it is easy to handle. Strings are allocated on the GC heap and they have to be properly disposed. Otherwise the memory will leak. If you remove the memory handling code from this sample, it will be not much different from the int case. Besides, if you decided to venture into the JNI area, you can't complain about the complexity.

Comment: Luckily, JNI provides a special wrapper for java.lang.String

Comment: JNI does not. At least not that I know about. However, there are several C++ libraries out there that do. For example, this one: https://github.com/mapbox/jni.hpp